# How to set connection timeout in Scalatra and Jetty?

Tags: scala, connection, timeout, jetty, scalatra

I am using Scalatra 2.4 with Jetty 9.2.10 and I am unable to set the connection timeout to 60 seconds.

I have tried both by adding the following to the web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

and by using connector.setIdleTimeout

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val server: Server = new Server
    val http_config: HttpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration
    val connector: ServerConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(http_config))
    val context: WebAppContext = new WebAppContext
    connector.setPort(8099)
    connector.setIdleTimeout(60000)
    context setContextPath "/"
    context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp")
    context.addEventListener(new ScalatraListener)
    context.addServlet(classOf[DefaultServlet], "/")
    server.setConnectors(Array(connector))
    server.setHandler(context)
    server.start()
    server.join()
  }
```

still, the connection with return **Gateway timeout** after 30 seconds.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: A "Gateway timeout" sounds like it's might be coming from some other place, like a proxy in between, rather than from your server itself.

Comment: Thanks Jose, but I get the same with both a remote connection or on my local machine (localhost)

Comment: Your configuration does not produce a ["Gateway timeout" from Jetty](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Gateway+timeout%22) (you are not using the Jetty proxy features).  Something else is producing that error for your.  (Perhaps your machine is setup for a machine-wide http_proxy ?)

Comment: I have no proxy setup on my machine and get the same error even when running locally and using localhost. I have tried multiple machines and get the same. The one thing in common is that I'm running it on Windows (though I've tried different versions too)

Comment: +1 for the question as with reducing the timeout via these configuration options e.g. to 10 seconds does not work too (and so increasing won't work) and I'm struggling to find the correct option.